# Integrate $\ln x \cos(\ln x) \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{\ln x\cdot \cos(\ln x)} {x}\,dx$$

How to calculate this integrate thank you very much

Comment: Substitute $u=\ln x$.

Comment: What have you tried? You should start with change of variable $t=\log x$, then $dt=\frac{dx}{x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the given
$$=\int\frac{\ln x.\cos(\ln x)}{x}dx$$
Make the substitution

put $\ln x=t$ then $\frac{1}{x}dx=dt \implies \frac{dx}{x}=dt$
$$=\int{t.\cos(t)dt}$$
integrating by parts
$$=t.\sin(t)-\int{1.\sin(t)dt}$$
$$=t.\sin(t)-(-\cos(t))$$
$$=t.\sin(t)+\cos(t)$$
Now as $\ln x = t$. Solution become
$$=\ln x.\sin(\ln x)+\cos(\ln x)$$

Answer (score 6):

As suggested, try the following: let $\ln x = u$

$$ \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$

$$ \int \frac{\ln x\cos(\ln x)}{x} dx = \int{u\cos u} du$$

You can then integrate by parts.

Comment: The solution must be (lnx)sin(lnx)-cos(lnx)+C

Answer (score 1):

Letting $t=\ln x \implies \Bbb d t = \frac {\Bbb d x} {x}$, we obtain $\int {t \cos t \; \Bbb d t}$.

Using integration by parts, we get:

$$\begin{split} \int {t \cos t \; \Bbb d t} &=t \int \cos t \; \Bbb d t - \int {\left[ \frac {\Bbb d t} {\Bbb d t} \int \cos t \; \Bbb d t \right] \Bbb d t}\\
&=t \sin t  - \int \sin t \; \Bbb d t \\
&=t \sin t + \cos t + C\\
&= \ln x \sin (\ln x) - \cos (\ln x)  + C
\end{split}$$

Comment: Please format your answer correctly